# URL redirect from event handlers in React v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new to React, and I am having an issue redirecting to a new page using JavaScript event handlers. I don't know what I am not getting right.

## App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Nav, {Jumbotron} from '../partials/headobjs';
import Footer from '../partials/footer';
import Users from '../components/user';
import UserObj from '../components/userobj';
import Err404 from '../components/err404';

//import css files.. 
import '../css/styles.css';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Nav />      
          <Jumbotron/>   

          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Users}/>
            <Route path='/user' component={UserObj}/>
            <Route component={Err404} />
          </Switch>

          <div className='clr'></div>

          <Footer />
      </div>      
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

## Users.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

class Users extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = { 
      name:aminu
    };
  }

  gotoURL(usr){
    let url = `/user/${usr}`;
    //console.log(url);
    return <Redirect to={url}/>
  }

  render() {    
     return (    
        <div className="container">
             <button onClick={this.gotoURL.bind(this, this.state.name)}>
               Go to {this.state.name} page
            </button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Users;
```

I want the function `gotoURL` to redirect to a new route, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, I have tried using the `browserHistory`, and now I'm trying out the `<Redirect/>` class but yet to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Redirect` component needs to be rendered and not returned to the onClick handler which is why it is not working. You can make use of `history.push` instead

```
gotoURL(usr){
    let url = `/user/${usr}`;
    //console.log(url);
    this.props.history.push(url);
  }
```

Comment: that simple, how come i didnt come across this, thanks boss.. working..

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Comment: Perfect. Simple solution and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirect from function, use render method and state to workout with `redirect` problem

```
class Users extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            name:'aminu',
            toUser: false
        };
    }

    gotoURL(usr){
        let url = `/user/${usr}`;
        //console.log(url);
        this.setState({toUser:true, goto: url})
    }

    render() {

        if (this.state.toUser === true) {
            return <Redirect to={this.state.goto}/>
        }

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <button onClick={this.gotoURL.bind(this, this.state.name)}>
                    Go to {this.state.name} page
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Link component from react-v4 to change your route.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<div className="container">
    <Link to={`/user/${usr}`}
        <button>
          Go to {this.state.name} page
        </button>
    </Link>
</div>
```